# Best way to connect to a MySQL server in windows using dial-up connection using VB.NEt 2005

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio, network-programming

I have a client that wants to connect to his MySQL database using Dial-up/Modem connection. All i know is a phone number. I will be using VB.NET 2005 for this project. We also have a LAN Connection setup to other computer, but some of this computer only uses Dial-up to connect. The LAN connection works fine because i can just use the Local IP to create a connection string.

But my problem is how do i get to connect to a remote server using a Dial-up? I know building a connection string require an IP to connect. Do i need to get the IP after a dial-up connection is connected or to i need to use different approach?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here's the setup:
I have a server and i have 10+ clients, the server has a T1 connection + a dial-up modem installed also.
I created a POS system to all the clients, Some clients uses dial-up some uses LAN. What the server do is all the records of the clients POS will be sync to one database on the server in one table. If i'm in the server and and i selected a station/client and click SYNC button all the records on that client will be sync to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A network aware program does not typically concern itself with the mechanics of making the  connection. What if the client switches to cable modem? ISDN? Gets a T1? Uses WIFI from their phone? It should not matter to your program at all.

That said... if you really have to do this, there are command-line utilities in Windows to initiate dial-up connections. You can use Process.Start() to execute rasdial, for instance.

As for "getting the IP"... that has nothing to do with your connection being made. The server's IP is the same.

EDIT: If you mean that the *server* is on dial-up, you have a problem. A server should be available when ever it needs to be connected to. You should look into getting inexpensive virtual server hosting somewhere, if that's the case.

Comment: The server has DSL connection and a dial-up modem also.

Comment: I strongly recommend against trying to use a dial-up connection for incoming connections. How do you assure it is *always* available? If you solve that, you should use something like dyndns.com to get a hostname you can use for connecting to it, instead of an IP address.